# Update the total price dynamic

Tags: apex, visualforce

i have the pageblocktable with multiple quantity inputField as the user enters the value I need to do calculations which is (qty*0.25) and display the total price. this must be done in real time, meaning as soon as user enter the value the total should be calculate.

Visualforce page:

display the Total cost:

```
<apex:pageBlockSection title="Total" collapsible="false" columns="2" id="pbs"> 
    <apex:pageBlockSectionItem > Total Cost: {!totalCost }   </apex:pageBlockSectionItem>
<apex:pageBlockSectionItem >
```

pageblockTable:

```
<apex:pageBlock>
  <apex:pageBlockTable value="{!products}" var="a">                     
          <apex:column headerValue="quantity" >                            
                <apex:inputField id ="qty" value="{!a.ali.qty}" required="true" />                      
          </apex:column>
  </apex:pageBlockTable>
</apex:pageBlock>
```

Any help/pointers how this can be done?

Comment: Use javascript to add all the element values and populate the total. Or use remote actions or partial page refreshes.......lots of ways to do it. Have you done any reading / research yet?

Comment: i haven't done remote actions but i have tried to do with actionscript using onkeyup but that does not work.

Comment: Eric has a better idea but if you don't want to use javascript and can tolerate a small (1+ sec) delay in refresh, then onchange event with actionSupport + rerender of `pbs` can let the controller calc the total. This would be a somewhat annoying UX